# margins with landscape and page header

Tags: marginpar, pdflscape, lscape

I use the scrreprt class with a page header. I also use margin notes. It looks good in portrait mode. 
[image]
However, some pages may be rotate. In that case, this looks ugly. 
[image]
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\ohead{\pagemark{}}

\newcommand{\examplepage}{
  \lipsum[1]
  \marginpar{This is a marginal note.}
  \lipsum[2-4]
}

\begin{document}
\examplepage{}

\begin{landscape}
\examplepage{}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

What can I do to improve the page layout in landscape?

Comment: The problem is not depending on KOMA-Script's `scrreprt` or `scrlayer-scrpage`. It also happens with, e.g., `report` + `\pagestyle{headings}` + at least one chapter heading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\reversemarginpar` inside the `landscape` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\ohead{\pagemark{}}

\newcommand{\examplepage}{
  \lipsum[1]
  \marginpar{This is a marginal note.}
  \lipsum[2-4]
}

\begin{document}
\examplepage{}

\begin{landscape}
\reversemarginpar
\examplepage{}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Addendum: For `twoside` documents `\ifthispageodd{\reversemarginpar}{}{}` would do the same automatically. Without KOMA-Scrpt class, `\ifthispageodd` needs package `scrextend`. Other packages provide similar features.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I think the O.P.'s problem comes from being in `landscape, so the outer margin is indeed the top margin, which is not large enough.

Comment: The outer margin with class option `twoside` (or `scrbook` instead of `scrreprt`) would change between odd and even pages. So it is not longer *always* the top margin. The OP does not use this option, but maybe another user will and would have the same problem. And if you add `twoside` to the options and add another `landscape` environment, the `\reversemarginpar` would be wrong in the copy. That's the reason for my addendum. It is not a critic. Your answers is correct and I've already voted for it.